# Multiprocessing - Occupies all CPU cores

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have implemented python multi-processing. Following is the code.

```
import multiprocessing

manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
return_dict = manager.dict()

for dev, value in device_dict.items():
    tmp_dict = {}
    tmp_dict[dev]= value      
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=myfunc, args=(tmp_dict,return_dict,))
    threads.append(p)

for x in threads:
    x.start()

for x in threads:
    x.join()

pqd = dict(return_dict)
```

the `device_dict` dictionary has 30 elements, so 30 processes are instantiated.
After adding multi-processing, my code running time has significantly reduced say from 1 hr 20 mins to 20 mins only on a 8 core processor.
When I run  the same code on a 54 core processor, it again takes 20 mins. Shoudln't it reduce? Also all the cores are occupied though there are only 30 process. Can someone point anything wrong with this code.

Comment: We would need to know what `myfunc` does in order to tell you more. "Embarrassingly parallel" problems can scale almost linearly with the number of cores, but that not likely in your case. The processes might compete for some shared resources or do some IO operations. Say you took some virtual machine with bunch of cores and HDD. If you read / write to drive, the head need to jump back and forth, effectively slowing down the whole thing. That's just one scenario.

Comment: @LukaszTracewski its a huge function with a lot of sub-functions. I will try to cut it and post it. Btw has you have stated all processes update a common variable called "return_dict" maybe each process is waiting for the resource and hence the delay. Is the understanding correct?

Comment: It all depends on what happens in the code. How often do you update it? In general I'd avoid passing as an argument your return variable. You're better off using Pool.